Why is the string always at the forefront of the struct?
eg:
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)\]
public struct Test
{

     public int age;
    
     public int i1;
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
     public string str;

}

and i  check   them position,the  string type is  the forefront of the struct.
This doesn't seem to be the same location as defined in my struct

I'd like to know why this address is at the forefront.

Taking a quick loot at the docs for LayoutKind Enum it sounds like sequential doesn't mean in the same order as they are defined. You would need to use LayoutKind.Explicit for that.

As far as i know it is an optimization technique in order to ensure for references become loaded onto cache line, ie access time concern. For the same reason MT-reference in classes is placed at the beginning of every object. Structs containing reference types are no longer treated as unmanaged and LayoutKind,Sequential setup explicity  is ignored for them.

You might also check Why does LayoutKind.Sequential work differently if a struct contains a DateTime field? which hints at the complexity involved.
